# X accel redirect not downloading the file

Tags: django, nginx, x-accel-redirect

I'm trying to add authentication to allow only valid users to download static files from nginx.

This is my Nginx configuration :

```
location ^~ /download-logs {
    internal;
    alias media/logs;
}
```

And in Django I've added a route to handle the response :

```
url   :  url(r'^media/', views.protectedMedia, name="protect_media"),
views : 
def protectedMedia(request):
    response = HttpResponse(status=200)
    response['Content-Type'] = ''
    response['X-Accel-Redirect'] = '/download-logs/log.txt'
    return response
```

When i try to go to the route `http://my_ip_address/media/` from the response i can see X accel redirect field, but file is not getting downloaded

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved, basically i forgot to pass the proxy for my uwsgi server in nginx configuration...

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api;
}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Here are the complete steps which I've followed:

https://medium.com/@pavanskipo/how-to-serve-protected-content-using-x-accel-nginx-django-fd529e428531